# Core dump truncated although ulimit set to unlimited

Tags: truncate, coredump, ulimit

My app core dump is getting truncated always. I have set `ulimit` to unlimited. Also I have enough disk space. And I am not killing the process while core dumping is going on. Any other possibilities for core getting truncated ?

Comment: What do you confirm that it is truncated?

Comment: When i run gdb it says core file is truncated.

Comment: What is `ulimit -a` shows for you? Want to see the file size as reported by ulimit

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 54739
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240

Comment: cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 54739
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
[root@localhost ~]# pwd

Comment: You may update your question description as comments cannot hold formatting.